# Setting Sealed to False... Any repercussions?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, content-type, folder

I need to attach an event receiver to a content type created by SharePoint:

```
        FolderCT.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, SharepointReceiversAssemblyName, CTReceiverName);
        FolderCT.Update();
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

> Folder at "/" is sealed

So, to go around the problem - I'm running the whole snippet under elevated privileges, and I'm setting Sealed to false. **Is this a bad idea?**

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPContentType FolderCT = web.ParentWeb.ContentTypes[SPBuiltInContentTypeId.Folder];
            FolderCT.Sealed = false;
            FolderCT.Update();

            FolderCT.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdding, SharepointReceiversAssemblyName, CTReceiverName);
            FolderCT.Update();

            FolderCT.Sealed = true;
            FolderCT.Update();
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you reseal it again, as you do, I do not see a problem.

Here's a snippet regarding the purpose of sealing:

> Sometimes, you want to make absolutely sure that someone can’t go in
>   and change your content type via the Windows SharePoint Services user
>   interface.  If an administrator were to delete or rename columns in
>   your content type this can cause all sorts of issues as things may or
>   may not be prorogated down to the child types.  You might also want to
>   ensure that a content type is only created / modified by using a
>   feature and CAML.   To solve this, a content type can be marked as
>   sealed and it can only be marked as sealed through the object model. 
>   This prevents any casual changes to the content type via the user
>   interface.

from http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2009/03/11/how-to-seal-a-content-type.aspx